# how to auto trigger click data-binding knockout

Tags: knockout.js

In `post` I have a data member `loginUserId` what holds the id of current login user. I want to use this id in comment and comment reply functions to authenticate whether user can edit comment or not. For this I have tried two tricks but none of them is working.

```
<script>
    function post(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.loginUserId = data.loginUserId;
        self.comments = ko.observableArray();
        //other stuff
        if (data.comment) {
            var cmt = $.map(data.comment, function (item) { return new comment(item); });
            self.Comments(cmt);
        }
    }
    function comment(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.postedById = data.postedById;
        //some stuff
        self.isEditable = function (userId,loginUserId) {
            if (userId == loginUserId) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.posts = ko.observableArray();
        self.loadpost = function () {
            //load using ajax and map in post 
        }
        self.loadpost();
        return self;
    }

    $(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
    })
</script>


<span data-bind="foreach:posts">
    <span data-bind="text:loginUserId"></span>
    <span data-bind="foreach:comments">
        <span data-bind="text:postedById"></span>
        <span data-bind="text:description"></span>
        <span data-bind="visible: function(){ isEditable($parent.loginUserId,$data.postedById)}">edit</span>
        @* second trick. Not sure even "if" executes the function
        <span data-bind="if:function(){$data.postedById == $parent.loginUserId}">
            <span data-bind="click:editComment"> edit </span>
        </span>*@
        </span>
</span>
```

Now `isEditable` is not triggered itself. How to trigger `isEditable` function.

**Update:** 
Please don't consider `editComment` function. I will handle it myself. I just want that "edit" should be shown to only that user who is authorized to edit comment.

Comment: Please post the rest of your code. Making a fiddle would really help as well.

Comment: I have edited question. Hope it will help

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you're using aren't returning anything, which means they'll always return `undefined` (which is falsy). Either return the result of the equality check or just don't wrap it in a function (Knockout will handle wrapping it and using the return value).

```
<span data-bind="if: postedById === $parent.loginUserId">
    <span data-bind="click: editComment"> edit </span>
</span>
```

Comment: yes, I am using exectly same but when page is loaded it does not go to editcomment function. How to trigger this function?

Comment: Your code doesn't show *where* you've defined `editComment`. I assumed it was in `Comment` because that's how it appears you are currently calling it.

Comment: Ok. I just want that "edit" should be shown to that user who is authorized to edit comment.